# Understanding cypress clock() and tick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I've created this simple React app in order to understand how [Cypress clocks](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Syntax) work:

```
function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>inputRef.current.value = "foo",20000)
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" data-cy="my-input"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically, the app waits 20 seconds and then sets the input value to "foo".

I'm trying to assert this logic using a Cypress clock:

```
describe("My Input",()=>{
    beforeEach(()=>{
        cy.visit('/')
    })

    it("should get a value of foo after 20 seconds",()=>{
        cy.clock()
        cy.tick(20000);
        cy.get('[data-cy=my-input]').should('have.value','foo');
    })
})
```

I've tried multiple things like calling `cy.clock()` inside the `beforeEach` clause an using the yielded `clock` in the assertion: `cy.clock().then(clock => clock.tick(20000))` but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I never used clock() method but it seems like the tick() function gets called before your component gets rendered. Try to add a guard to wait for the component to be rendered like
a cy.get('[data-cy=my-input]') before the cy.clock()

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, eventually I managed to get my test to work by moving the `clock()` call to a `before` callback:

```
before(()=>{
        cy.clock();
        cy.visit('/')
    })

    it("should get a value of foo after 20 seconds",()=>{
        cy.get('[data-cy=my-input]')
        cy.tick(20000);
        cy.get('[data-cy=my-input]').should('have.value','foo');
    })
```

Not sure why doing the same inside a `beforeEach` doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: Note that, as described [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Behavior), `cy.clock()` needs to be called _before_ your `cy.visit()` command. The above code should also work in a `beforeEach()` as long as `cy.clock()` is called before `cy.visit()`.

Comment: Thanks @candrews, solved my issue as well!